# Ruby newb: how do I extract a substring?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to scrape a CBS sports page for shot data in the NBA.
Here is the page I'm starting out with and using as a sample: http://www.cbssports.com/nba/gametracker/shotchart/NBA_20131115_MIL@IND

In the source, I found a string that contains all the data that I need. This string, in the webpage source code, is directly under var CurrentShotData = new.

What I want is to turn this string in the source into a string I can use in ruby. However, I'm having some trouble with the syntax. Here's what I have.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'mechanize'

a = Mechanize.new
a.get('http://www.cbssports.com/nba/gametracker/shotchart/NBA_20131114_HOU@NY') do    |page|
shotdata = page.body.match(/var currentShotData = new String\(\"(.*)\"\)\; var  playerDataHomeString/m)[1].strip
print shotdata
end
```

I know I must be doing this wrong... it seems so needlessly complex and on top of that it isn't working for me. Could someone enlighten me on the simple way to get this string into Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace:

```
shotdata = page.body.match(/var currentShotData = new String\(\"(.*)\"\)\; var  playerDataHomeString/m)[1].strip
```

with:

```
shotdata = page.body.match(/var currentShotData = new String\(\"(.*?)\"\)\; var  playerDataHomeString/m)[1].strip
```

changing the `(.*)` with `(.*?)` will cause a [*lazy evaluation*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) (matching of *minimal* number of characters) of the string which is the behavior you want.

Comment: That didn't work. Could it be that there is a line break between the ");" and the "var playerDataHomeString"?

Comment: @user3000487 can you post an example for a valid value of `page.body` ?

Comment: A valid value? Not quite sure what that means. When I put in just page.body instead of all that other stuff, it prints the entire source code of the page. I just need to be able to search the string that is the source code and extract this one set of numbers.

Edit: Sorry, got it working now. The problem was the line break, but thanks to your lazy evaluation I don't even need anything except the ");". Thanks so much.

Comment: @user3000487 add `puts page.body` to your code and post the output (add it to your question).